# Dynamic summarise throught dynamic multiplication for an external vector

Tags: r

I have a tibble such:

```
X = tibble(Name = rep(c("A","B","C"),5),
       Coeffs_1 = runif(15,0,1),
       Coeffs_2 = runif(15,0,1)) %>% arrange(Name)

Y = runif(10,0,100)
```

In this example the amount of "Reps" per "Names" is arbitrarily fixed at 5, and the amount of Coeffs_2 is arbitrarily fixed at 2, but in my code they could be any number and I don't know the exact number.

I also have a vector with n = reps*2 elements:

```
Y = runif(10,0,100)
```

In this specific case, it's 10 = 5*2.

My task is to summarise, per each Name, per each Coeff, this formula:

```
Result_x[1] = sum(Coeff_x[1]*Y[2] + Coeff_x[2]* Y[3] + ... + Coeff_x[Reps]*Y[Reps+1]) - Y[1]
Result_x[2] = sum(Coeff_x[1]*Y[3] + Coeff_x[2]* Y[4] + ... + Coeff_x[Reps]*Y[Reps+2]) - Y[2]
.
.
.
Result_x[Reps] = sum(Coeff_x[1]* Y[Reps+1] + Coeff_x[2]* Y[Reps+2] + ... + Coeff_x[Reps]*Y[Reps*2]) - Y[Reps]
```

So that in the end, the final summarise tibble should look like:

| Name | Lag | Result_1 | ... | Result_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | +1 | a number | numbers | a number |
| A | +2 | a number | numbers | a number |
| A | ... | a number | numbers | a number |
| A | Reps | a number | numbers | a number |
| B | +1 | a number | numbers | a number |
| B | +2 | a number | numbers | a number |
| ... | ... | a number | numbers | a number |
| ... | Reps | a number | numbers | a number |

The dynamic nature of the issue makes hard for me to define it well with a for cycle, and the presence of the external vector that must be re-indexed and properly summarised for each row in the original tibble makes me difficult to work with a pipeline.

I thought that defining a custom function could help but again, it messes with pipeline code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the 'X' by 'Name', loop over the `list` (`map`), while creating `shift`ed `lead` values of 'Y' in a `list` with `n` specified as a `vector`.  Loop over the `list`, `summarise` `across` the 'Coeff' columns for each of the nested `list` by taking the `sum` of product of the column value with the corresponding 'y' length corrected and subtract from the `first` value of 'y'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
X %>% 
   group_split(Name) %>% 
   map_dfr(~ map_dfr(shift(Y, n = 1:nrow(.x), type = 'lead'), 
        function(y) .x %>% 
      summarise(Name = first(Name), across(starts_with('Coeff'),  
         ~ sum(. * y[seq_along(.)], na.rm = TRUE) - first(y)))) ) %>%
   mutate(Lag = rowid(Name))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   Name  Coeffs_1 Coeffs_2   Lag
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1 A        127.      54.4     1
 2 A        162.     134.      2
 3 A        127.      68.2     3
 4 A        109.      38.0     4
 5 A        108.      94.0     5
 6 B        175.     197.      1
 7 B        187.     240.      2
 8 B        151.     200.      3
 9 B        132.     159.      4
10 B        102.     152.      5
11 C         48.8    131.      1
12 C         89.1    128.      2
13 C         42.5     98.7     3
14 C         29.4     95.7     4
15 C         41.7     50.1     5
```

Comment: I think there are 2 errors.

The first can be easily corrected with a %>% mutate(). At the end of each string in the formula there is `- Y[1]`

The second, as much as I understand it, is that each string ends at `Reps+1` AND it has `Reps` addends, instead

each vector in `(shift(Y, n = 1:nrow(.x), type = 'lead')` has `Reps*2` elements, within an increasing numbers of NA. All the elements after the `Reps` have to be discarded.

Comment: @GiulioGCantone can you check the updated code

Comment: For example, if

`Coeff_1 = c(.5,.5.,5,.5,1)`

and

`Y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

`Result_1` would be: `sum(2*.5,3*.5,4*.5,5*.5,6*1) - 1`
`Result_2` would be: `sum(3*.5,4*.5,5*.5,6*.5,7*1) - 2`

And since there are 5 elements in `Coeff_1` (in this case `Reps = 5`), there would be a
`Result_5: sum(6*.5,7*.5,8*.5,9*.5,10*1) - 5`

but not a `Result_6`.

Comment: @GiulioGCantone Yes, that is why I subset the `y` with `y[seq_along(.)]` to match the number of rows of the data in the list where `y` is the shifted list element